# JavaScript: Is it possible to handle server errors from `form.submit()`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I normally use Ajax for form submission, but there is one case where this isn't possible. This particular form has to trigger a file download from the server, and the browser must produce a 'save as' dialog. I have to do this the old way (I think), with a form submission that returns an attachment.

To do this, I create a form with JavaScript:

```
   var form = document.createElement("form");
   form.setAttribute("method", "post");
   form.setAttribute("action", "/cgi-bin/myprog");
   ...create and append lots of input elements, and then
   form.submit();
```

This works fine, until the server has to return an error. If the server returns `403 Forbidden`, for example, then the browser just shows a blank page and tries to redirect to `/cgi-bin/myprog`.

Is there any way to handle errors with `submit()`? The [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.4) only seems to say `User agents should render the response from the HTTP "get" and "post" transactions`. The HTMLFormElement [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-40002357) doesn't say anything about errors. I control the server, and can change the response, so I could potentially return `200 OK` with an error message, but there must be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it's not possible, so you have to check in advance whether or not the download will succeed. In my case, I only need to check whether the user is authorised to access the file.

I handle this by sending a separate Ajax request to the server, which returns success (`200`) if the user is authorised, and failure otherwise (`403`, or whatever). If success is returned (ie. the `textStatus` parameter to `.always` is `success`), then I construct and submit the form as above.